# How to prevent the loading of background image in each page?

Tags: css, html, jquery-mobile, ios6, background-image

I am using jquery mobile. I have defined a background image in index page inside css body{}  tag. Back ground is coming fine but it's automatically loading in different pages also though I didn't declare the body css part in following pages. How to prevent that? and css body{background: url()} is only working on index page. here is my code

```
        <style type="text/css">
            body {
                background: url(images/login2.png);
                background-repeat:repeat-y;
                background-position:center;
                background-attachment:scroll;
                background-size:100% 100% ;
            }
            .ui-page {
                background: transparent;
            }
            .ui-content{
                background: transparent;
            }
            </style>

        </head>


<body>


        <div align="center" data-role="fieldcontain" id="contentConfirmation" name="contentConfirmation">


            <div >
                <label class="userlabelclass" for="url" style="float:left" ><p>Username:</p></label>
                <input class="userfieldclass" id="Lusername" name="uid_r" type="text" value="John Doe" " style="width:230px;float:right">
              </div>  


    <div >
                    <label class="pswdlebelclass" for="url" style="float:left"><p>Password:</p></label>
                    <input class="pswdfieldclass" id="Lpassword" name="pwd_r" type="password" value="123456789" style="width:230px;float:right">
                    <label class="forgotclass" for="url" style="float:left"><p>Forgot Password?</p></label>


    </div>


         <div align="center">
                <a href="listview_page.html" data-role="button" data-inline="true" data-theme="e" class="buttonclass" >Log In</a>
         </div>
   </div>

</body>
```

Comment: Can we clarify: You only want to display the background image on one page and it is displaying on all pages?

Comment: yes. That is exactly what's happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jquery mobile navigation uses Ajax to load the `body` part only of the pages you navigate to. This means that the `header` of subsequent pages is ignored, and that the `header` of your first page is "applied" to all pages. If you want your background to apply only to your first page, I would recommend:

1. you create a `data-role="page"` div to hold the content of your first page, as recommended when using jquery mobile
2. You apply your background to this specific page element